# Is there any difference between * operator used in declaration (int *p = &i) and expression (*p = &i)

Tags: c, pointers, variable-assignment

Why is

```
int i;
int *p = &i;
```

right, while

```
int i, *p;
*p = &i;
```

is wrong?

Is there any difference between `*` operator used in declaration (`int *p = &i`) and expression (`*p = &i`)?

Comment: There is no `*` operator in the p variable definition.

Comment: In a *declaration*, `*` is not an operator.  In a *statement*, `*p` is of type `int`.

Comment: The first one is declaring `p` as an int pointer and pointing it at `i`. The second one is storing the address of `i` as an integer in the location pointed at by `p`.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be; Then what it is?

Comment: @haccks Part of the type declaration of the `p` variable.

Comment: *p=&i gets an uninitialized vraiable into undefined address. So you dont know what and where you moved. Absolute undefinedness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is difference - in the first form `*` is part of the type definition `int *`.

In the second form its an unary dereference operator. Also there is an error with the second expression - when you are assigning to a pointer, there is no need to dereference it.

`(*p)` evaluates to type `int` while `p` evaluates to type `int *`; `&i` evaluates to type `int *`. Hence assinging the address of int variable i to pointer p should read `p=&i;`

Answer (score 3):

In your second code block, this:

```
int i, *p;
*p = &i;
```

can be fixed to:

```
int i, *p;
p = &i;
```

`p` is still declared as a pointer to an `int`, but you want to store the address of `i` to `p`.

In your code, `*p = &i` stores the address of `i` to some area in memory that `p` points to (since you didn't initialize it).